# BusyBox message when trying to boot a persistent USB stick

Tags: boot, usb

I created a persistent ubuntu using the mkusb tool. It's working fine on my Ubuntu laptop but when I tried it on an 64 bit HP laptop I saw the message about BusyBox instead of seeing the Ubuntu desktop:

[image]

Any ideas what can it be and where should I start my investigation?

Comment: BTW, The laptop is dell latitude e7470

Comment: I see the same message on HP ProBook 450 G1. 12GB RAM, Intel Core i3-4005U CPU.